# What is actually meant by 'collection' in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs

I am new to Team Foundation server.

1)What is meant by collection in TFS?

2)How can me and my friends work on a project using TFS?

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1)What is meant by collection in TFS?

Simply saying **a team project collection is a group of team projects** in TFS.

When your Team Foundation Server (TFS) hosts multiple team projects, you can manage them more efficiently by grouping them together and assigning the same resources to them. For example, you can group projects that have similar requirements or objectives, such as all team projects that access a particular code base. You can then manage the group of team projects as an autonomous resource with its own user groups, server resources, and maintenance schedule.

**A group of team projects is called a team project collection.** When you install TFS, a default collection is created to contain all team projects. When you create a collection, you specify the logical and physical resources that team projects within that collection can use. All the artifacts and data that those team projects use are stored in the single database of the collection.

See [Manage team project collections in Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/manage-team-project-collections?view=tfs-2018) for details.

> 2)How can me and my friends work on a project using TFS?

Too much content for this question. Suggest you reading the [Quickstarts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/install/get-started?view=tfs-2018) documents first.

Basically you need to do following things first:

1. [Create a team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/create-team-project?toc=/vsts/tfs-server/toc.json&bc=/vsts/tfs-server/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=tfs-2018)
2. [Add users to a team project or specific team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/add-users-team-project?toc=/vsts/tfs-server/toc.json&bc=/vsts/tfs-server/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=tfs-2018)
3. [Add administrators, set permissions at the project-level or project
   collection-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?toc=/vsts/tfs-server/toc.json&bc=/vsts/tfs-server/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=tfs-2018)
4. Connect to TFS --> Version Control --> Build/Release

Please refer to the Guide link for each related point : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/?view=vsts#pivot=start

Also here is a simple guide for your reference to [Get Started with Team Foundation Server 2015](https://tfs.discountasp.net/kb/a1372/getting-started-with-team-foundation-server-2015.aspx)

Comment: @automaticSoldier Is the answer helpful for you? any update?